# How to index a user input list in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, indexing

want user to input the names of the cities he has been, and I want the script to store each of them individually.

I made this part working all right.

Then, for the sake of the project, the script should ask where each city is located at. But now, it works like this:

input:

```
Paris, Hamburg, London...
```

output:

```
Where is Paris located?
Where is Hamburg located?
Where is London located?
...
```

**Code:**

```
user_cities = raw_input("What cities have you visited so far?").split(", ")
if len(user_cities) > 0:
    index = 0
    for city in user_cities:
        print "Where is "+str(city)+" located?", 
        index+=1
```

There one thing missing from the expected output:

> **How do we index and/or iterate a user input list?** I tried every piece of code in similar situations but none of them worked for me.
>
> We don't know how many cities he has been to. He can write just 1 city or 20 cities. I can hardcode, writing dozens of unnecessary lines, but I know there is a right way to do it. I can't remember how.

In the expected result, I want it to take turns to ask user where the city is located one by one.

input:

```
Paris, Hamburg, London...
```

output 1:

```
Where is Paris located?
```

input 1:

```
France
```

output 2:

```
Where is Hamburg located?
```

input 2:

```
Germany
```

etc.

Comment: instead of using `print`, use `raw_input` if you want it to wait for user input each time. also, what are you using index for...?

Comment: You might want to end up with a dictionary of {city: country} entries, and then you can `locations[city] = raw_input("Where is "+str(city)+" located?"`

Comment: Why are you using indices at all? Why not a `for ... in` loop?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Not sure why they're using an index, but they ARE using a `for` loop.

Comment: Wouldn't this code already do what the OP wants? I don't understand what this question is asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an infinite loop with some sort of sentinel for the user to indicate "Okay no more." How about:

```
cities = []
while True:
    city = raw_input("Enter a city you've been to (or press enter to exit): ")
    if city == '':  # no input -- this is your sentinel
        break  # leave the loop
    else:
        cities.append(city)
```

Then you can prompt for the countries if you wanted to do that separately for some reason.

```
countries = []
for idx, city in enumerate(cities):
    country = raw_input("Where is " + city + " located? ")
    countries.append(country)
    # why did you need the index? enumerate is the way to go now....
```

Maybe you need a dictionary then?

```
cities_to_countries = dict(zip(cities, countries))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed. Also thanks to other commentators. I thought I needed index, but looks like what I need are dictionary, enumerate and append. No wonder I couldn't find the solution using indices.

Comment: @StanleyWilkins I'm sure you could do it with indices too, but it's not immediately apparent what your "final result" should be so it's hard for me to give you direct guidance as to how to get there. `enumerate` just gives you access to the index WHILE you iterate, so...